# Application Running Security Exception

Tags: android

Problem When Running the app:
In Consol Screen

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
>   flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.test.sample/.Setting } from null (pid=9137,
>   uid=2000) requires null

Comment: Have you set all permissions, you need in the manifest ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enough permissions `<uses-permission>`. Look at the following guide about security in android http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html